# Show that $x^5+x+1=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

My work:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by$f(x)=x^5+x+1$

I calculated $f(-2)=-33$ and $f(1)=3$, then $0\in [f(-2),f(1)]$

So by Intermediate value theorem, and knowing that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=0$

Therefore the equation given admits a solution.
Correct ?
And also how could I prove that this solution is unique ?

Comment: the derivative is always positive, so the function is strictly increasing everywhere.

Comment: Your solution is basically correct, but $\;\Bbb R\;$ being connected (even path connected) has nothing to do here and you may want to write that polynomials are continuous functions. About uniqueness of the solution read the above comment.

Comment: Oh thanks , but  to apply intermediate value theorem shouldn't the domain of the function be connected ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès Details may depend on how your specific formulation of the IVT reads. Typical formulations start "Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous ..." and while the reason for the theorem to work is the connectedness of $[a,b]$, it is not specifically mentioned as premise (it's just that intervals *are* connected anyway)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your work appears to be correct.  To prove this solution is unique, note that

$$f\left(x\right) = x^5 + x + 1$$

means that

$$f'\left(x\right) = 5x^4 + 1$$

which is always $\ge 1$ as $x^4 \ge 0$ for all real $x$.  Thus, $f$ is a strictly increasing function.

You could also graph the function to see this.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

Assume there is an other zero, i.e.

$x_0,x_1$, where $x_1 >x_0$.

MVT.

$\dfrac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}=0=f'(a)$, where $a \in (x_0,x_1).$

But $f'(x)=5x^4+1 >0$, contradiction.